# Custom DataSet.Table.FindBy method

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a strongly-typed DataSet that was created using visual studio 2010's Configuration Wizard. I can find a DataRow easily as long as I know the primary key (see [How to: Edit Rows in a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

The problem occurs when I don't know the PK. Is there a way to create a custom method that returns a DataRow if you have a combination of columns that could also be a composite primary key (unique constraint). Using the example from the link, I would like to do something like this:

```
NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow customersRow = northwindDataSet1.Customers.FindByCustomerNameAndType("TestCustomerName", "TestCustomerType");
```

This assumes their Northwind DB Customers Table has two columns (name and type) that could also be a composite key. And the the FindBYCustomerNameAndType method would map to

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Customers
 WHERE name = "TestCustomerName" AND type = "TestCustomerType"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string whereClause = "name = 'TestCustomerName' and type = 'TestCustomerType'";
DataRow[] x = northwindDataSet1.Customers.Select(whereClause);
if (x.Length > 0){
    CustomersRow customersRow = x[0] as CustomersRow;

    //other code here
}
```